# Check if oracle script is valid and will run ok on another database

Tags: database, oracle, toad, database-scripts

I'm wondering if there is a tool that will let me check if a oracle script will run fine on another database (if my script from DEV db will run ok on QA db). I don't want to run/execute anything there (I dont have permisson), I just want to verify that once someone runs the script, it will execute without errors. Is this possible at all?

I use Toad for Oracle as my current IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to take a copy of the production database into a test database and apply the script on the test database.

If you don't have a spare test database, you can recreate the DEV db from production (at least the structure) and run the test on your DEV database.

Comment: Yes this is what I do currently, but it would be more handy with a tool where I could "validate" a script or simulate it before even starting the process of copying the prod database to test etc